# Can copulas be used to measure dependence of $X$ and $Y$ when we are given a random sample $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$?

Tags: copula

Trying to understand what copulas are, I am reading from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) that:

"In probability theory and statistics, a copula is a multivariate cumulative distribution function for which the marginal probability distribution of each variable is uniform on the interval $[0, 1]$. Copulas are used to describe the dependence between random variables."

---

For linear dependencies, the most famous measure is that of correlation:

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, then
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\rho(X,Y)=\frac{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\text{Cov}(X,X)}\sqrt{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}}
\end{equation}

When we have a random sample $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)$ from $X$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,...,y_n)$ from $Y$, then we can estimate the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ by
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\hat{\rho}(X,Y)=
\frac
{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y}) }
{
 \sqrt{
  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x} )^2  
 }
 \sqrt{
  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y} )^2   
 }
}
\end{equation}

---

Before diving to the mathematical details and definitions of copulas, I am wondering if copulas can be used as a measure of dependence when we are given a random sample  $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)$ from $X$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,...,y_n)$ from $Y$ like Pearson correlation.

Pearson correlation can be used to measure liner dependencies both theoretically (1) and empirically (2). Do copulas have the same nice property? If so, which is the estimator?

Comment: Copulas define a joint model on $(X,Y)$ and are parameterised to assess the dependence between the two components, with one value of the parameter corresponding to probabilistic independence. Measures of dependence like correlation only return a number, whose difference from zero gives a quantification of linear dependence. The difficulty with dependence is that it is the complement of independence, hence can essentially be anything.

Comment: @Xi'an So the answer is probably negative, right?  In linear cases, correlation returns the degree of linearity, so a number like that might be fine in this case. However, I haven't thought until now that the complement of independence can be anything, which is totally true. But again, I can't imagine that there are other ways to study dependence other than reporting a number like any correlation coefficient. I am curious to see how copulas approach this problem!

Comment: Because copulas capture all information about dependence that is not already encoded in the marginal distributions, just about any numerical property of a copula (within reason) measures some aspect of dependence.  From this idea arise derivations of many standard coefficients of association.

Comment: Correlation only measures the degree of dependence. Copulas quantify the structure of dependence, linear and non-linear